# Broke front camera on Nexus 5 and can't use any camera app

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, nexus-5, camera

I just repaired a screen on my broken Nexus 5 but I also broke the front camera module. Now I can't get the camera app to work (for the back camera) or use Snapchat.

Is there a way to disable the front camera so these apps will open using the rear camera without trying to connect to the front camera and sending an error message?

I could get the back camera working before updating the phone when I went online so could it possibly be a software update. Any solutions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with the default camera app being out of date after an OS update, this inhibited it the rear camera working on any camera app problem resolved itself once the default camera app had updated